# Can't see my nav tag

Tags: html, css

I can't see my navigation tag. I'm new to HTML 5 and don't really understand why my CSS is messed up.
I'm trying to create a header that is the width of the screen (100%), but the nav is hidden and part of the article tag is in the header tag.
Here is my html:

```
<body>
<header id="header"><h1>Welcome</h1></header>
<nav id="navigation">Home | Profile | Login</nav>
<article id="article">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <section><h2>this is the search</h2>@RenderBody()</section>
    <section><h2>This is the most section</h2></section>
</article></body>
```

and here is my css:

```
body 
{
background-color: white;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#header
{
background-color: blue;

position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}

#navigation
{
background-color: pink;
}

#article
{
background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: position: fixed; is hiding the nav.

Comment: oh I see! I removed the position: fixed and I can see it all again. But there is space between each tag. How do I eliminate that space?

Comment: look into removing padding and margins. there are css files like reset and normalise that can take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove position: fixed to allow elements to display. Then a simple solution to adjust the spacing is to set the margin for each element to 0 using the * selector.

The * selector will select all elements...you use it like any other selector:

```
* { 
  margin: 0}
```

Comment: what is the * selector?

Comment: Added to the answer right before seeing your comment.

Comment: I tried adding margin: 0; to each element that I wanted to have no space between them and nothing happened. WHy do I need to have a * {margin: 0'} to get it to work?

Comment: Using the * selector is the easy way to remove the space, but if you want to affect each element separately to avoid affecting certain elements with the * selector, you could add the following to each element you wish to eliminate space on:                         margin: 0;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;